# Convert hex string to ASCII string in Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

In a Windows batch (cmd) file, I'd like to convert the contents of a hex string in the form

`4C6F67696300000000000000`

to its equivalent ASCII string, here "Logic".
The hex string is always same size (12 octets).
Note that it is null-terminated if string is less than 12 characters.
Only conversion of plain printable ASCII characters (20-7F) required.
Pure batch solutions preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `certutil` tool, see `certutil /?` for more info.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "hex=4C6F67696300000000000000"
echo !hex!> temp.hex
call certutil -decodehex temp.hex str.txt >nul
set /p str=<str.txt
echo:
( del temp.hex & del str.txt )>nul
echo Your decoded string is:"!str!".
endlocal
exit /b 0
```